# Fetching data in coredata

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, ios7

```
-(void)getRecords
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CustomerOrder"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError* error;

       NSArray *fetchedRecords = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    if (fetchedRecords)
    {
        if (fetchedRecords.count == 0) //create new Entity
        {
            NSLog(@"Balaiah babu");
        }

        else
        {
            int count =0;
            for (int i=0; i<fetchedRecords.count; i++) {


                CustomerOrder * record = [fetchedRecords objectAtIndex:i];
                NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",record.customer_id,record.order_id,record.outletLatitude,record.outletLongitude,record.trigger_days,record.trigger_end_date,record.trigger_from_time,record.trigger_no_days,record.trigger_radius,record.trigger_start_date,record.trigger_to_time);

                NSLog(@"%d",count++);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

here fetched Records array is showing nil.But it is going through loop and printing the values of the log.I don't know how it is happening.

Comment: How are you verifying that `fetchedRecords` is nil?

Answer (score 0):

**In .h File**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

**In .m File**

Fetch entity "Info"

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = 
 [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Info" 
             inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

fetch entity request

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setEntity:entity];
```

Fetch the records and handle an error

```
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = 
 [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request 
                                      error:&error] mutableCopy];

if (!mutableFetchResults)
    {
    Nslog(@"nil");
}
```

Save our fetched data to an array

```
NSLog(@"get_Result==%@",[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"fname"]);
```

Comment: It is still showing mutableFetchResults as nil but it is going to this
if (!mutableFetchResults)
    {
    Nslog(@"nil");
}